# How to create a table with buttons?

Tags: list-manipulation, button

I'd like to make a simple dice roller to be used in board games. A simple way to simulate a roll is:

```
d[n_] := RandomChoice[Range[n]]
```

Now, calling d[6] will roll a 6-sided die, and d[20] a 20 sided-die. To avoid typing the command each time, it can be made into a button:

```
Button["d20", Echo@d[20]]
```

I wanted to build a Button table to simulate the classic range of d4, d6, d8, d10, d12 and d20. My initial try of:

```
Table[Button["d" <> ToString[k], Echo@d[k]], {k, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}}]
```

fails to run. I got no better result with:

```
ButtonBar[Table["d" <> ToString[k] :> d[k], {k, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}}]]
```

How can I generate this list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
buttons = Button["d" <> ToString[#], Echo@d[#]] & /@ {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20};

Column[buttons]
```

or

```
ButtonBar["d" <> ToString[#] :> Echo@d[#] & /@ {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}]
```

Of course, from this example it's easy to customise the style.

For example, I would change d[n)] as follows:

```
d[n_] := "d" <> ToString[n] <> ": " <> ToString[RandomChoice[Range[n]]]
```

so that the output tells you which dice you rolled.

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer to use string expressions (~~) as opposed to concatenation (<>) ?

Comment: No, actually I think StringJoin (<>) would be more appropriate here :) I'll edit the answer with that!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`With[{k = k}, ...]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to inject the iterator values in the first argument in `Table`:

```
Table[With[{k = k}, Button["d" <> ToString[k], Echo@d[k]]], {k, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}}]
```

Alternatively, define a function outside `Table` and use it as the first argument in `Table`:

```
btn[x_] := Button["d" <> ToString[x], Echo@d[x]]
Table[btn[k], {k, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}}]
```

Similarly, for `ButtonBar`:

```
ButtonBar[Table[With[{k = k}, "d" <> ToString[k] :> Echo@d[k]], {k, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}}]]
```

or

```
rule[x_] := "d" <> ToString[x] :> Echo@d[x];
ButtonBar[Table[rule[k], {k, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}}]]
```

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering how it could be done that way, thanks.